# Django Forms - contents of field not showing in textarea

Tags: python, html, django

I have a textarea in my modelform. When i insert text in the textarea it will save this text. But it will not show the contents after POST. If i would add a input field referenced to the same field it will show the contents, as show in image below;

[image]

I tried adding a widget, but this seems to not be doing anything.

My models.py

```
class OrderHeader(models.Model):
    orderheader_comment = models.TextField(max_length=4000, null=True, blank=True)
```

My forms.py - tried with and without widget

```
class OrderHeaderForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(OrderHeaderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.form_tag = False

    class Meta:
        model = OrderHeader
        customers = Customer.objects.all()       
        widgets = {
            'orderheader_comment': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 20}),
        }
```

My HTML - for both the input and text area

```
  <input id="orderheader_comment" name="orderheader_comment" class="form-control" rows="3" 
              value="{{ form.orderheader_comment.value|default_if_none:"" }}"></input>
  <textarea id="orderheader_comment" name="orderheader_comment" class="form-control" rows="3" 
              value="{{ form.orderheader_comment.value|default_if_none:"" }}"></textarea>
```

How come my textarea does not show the contents of orderheader_comment?

Comment: are you sure it isn't just inserting default which you specified as `""` ?

Comment: Yes, i am sure. I tried with and without the default value.

Comment: a answer that was just deleted was correct. Removing the .value did the trick. Thank you